# What is wrong with this cocoapods script?

Tags: bash, cocoapods

```
/Users/**me**/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**my app**-buxhprinxwwxfuaewaiysxqrzrpd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/my: No such file or directory
```

It isn't recognizing the space in the file name. How should I fix this?

Comment: This simply means file or directory 'my' is not present. Can you check in the script where it is being used and also check path in finder for existence. Post cocoaPods script code to better understand the issue.

Comment: I went into the directory and found a folder with a name that had a space. The space was preventing cocoapods from working properly. I have been on a wild goose chase trying to rename my project ever since.

Comment: In your script code, variable which had this path just put that variable in "" to include space in folder name. Ex. "$path"

Comment: It isn't my script code. It's cocoapods. The script code is pretty confusing to look at. Even my friend who deals with that stuff a lot couldn't give me any big steps towards figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is : prg s . sh

```
cat prg\ s\ .\ sh 
echo OK
```

You can execute it :

```
$ ./prg\ s\ .\ sh 
$ ./p*\ s\ .\ *
```

OK